# Laravel search from two tables

Tags: php, laravel, search

i want make search engine that would search by given name in partnership table clients by row "name" but cant figure out how should i make it... For now search engine works perfect but i can search only through two columns that i have described. When i try to add column name 'name' it says that variable is undefined

Here is my model Client.php

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Client extends Model {
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'nip',
        'telephone',
        'email',
        'address'
    ];
    public function licenses() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\License');
    }
}
```

This is my model License.php

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class License extends Model {
    protected $fillable = [
        'productName',
        'licenseNumber',
        'fvNumber',
        'buyDate',
        'other',
        'client_id'
    ];
    public function client() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Client');
    }
}
```

And my Controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Request;
use DB;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Requests\CreateLicenseRequest;
use App\License;
use App\Client;

class LicensesController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $licenses = License::get();
        $search = \Request::get('search'); 
        $licenses = License::where('productName','like','%'.$search.'%')
            ->orWhere('licenseNumber','like','%'.$search.'%')
            ->orderBy('id')
            ->paginate(20);
        return view('admin.crm.licenses.all',compact('licenses'));
    }
```

Comment: Can you include what you've tried but ended up not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$licenses = License::where('productName','like','%'.$search.'%')
    ->orWhere('licenseNumber','like','%'.$search.'%')
    ->orWhereHas('client', function ($query) use ($search) {
        $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
    })
    ->orderBy('id')
    ->paginate(20);
```

This basically search your *client* relation *name* column.